# How i fix Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python

Hello I tried to fix this but I couldn't
This is my code:

```
import random

Cromosomas=[[random.randint(1, 1010) for i in range(3)] for j in range(800)]
Z=[]
Fitness=[]
P=[]
C=[]
Padres=[]

def funcOb(Arreglo):
    return 0.2*Arreglo[0]**2+0.08*Arreglo[1]**2+0.18*Arreglo[2]**2+0.1*(Arreglo[0]*Arreglo[1])+0.04*(Arreglo[0]*Arreglo[2])+0.06*(Arreglo[1]*Arreglo[2])-0.14*Arreglo[0]-0.11*Arreglo[1]-0.1*Arreglo[2]+120+abs(Arreglo[0]+Arreglo[1]+Arreglo[2]-1000)-10

for i in range(0,800):
    Z.append(funcOb(Cromosomas[i]))
for i in range(0,800):
    Fitness.append(1/(1+Z[i]))
total=sum(Fitness)

for i in range(0,800):
    P.append(Fitness[i]/total);
A=0
for i in P:
    A=A+i
    C.append(A)    
    
R=[random.random()for i in range(800)]
for i in range(0,800):
    for j in range(0,800):
    if R[i]<=C[j]:
        Cromosomas[i]=Cromosomas[j]
        break
def mutar(Arreglo1,Arreglo2):
    b=random.randint(0, 2)
    if Arreglo1[b]<=Arreglo2[b]:
    Arreglo2[b]=Arreglo1[b]
    return Arreglo2
    if Arreglo1[b]>=Arreglo2[b]:
    Arreglo1[b]=Arreglo2[b]
    return Arreglo1

for i in range(0,800):
    r=random.random()
    if r<(0.3):
    n=Cromosomas[i]
    if n not in Padres:
        Padres.append(n)
    r=0     

for i in range(0,len(Padres)-1):
    if len(Padres)==1:
    Cromosomas[i]=[Padres[i][0],Padres[i][1],Padres[i][2]] 
    else:
    lista=mutar(Padres[i],Padres[i+1])
    Cromosomas[i]=[lista[0],lista[1],lista[2]]
    
for i in range(0,480):
    Cromosomas[Cromosomas==random.randint(1, 2400)]=random.randint(1, 800)      

for m in range(0,800):
    print(funcOb(Cromosomas[m]))
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 59, in <module>
    print(funcOb(Cromosomas[m]))  
    File "main.py", line 10, in funcOb
    return 0.2*Arreglo[0]**2+0.08*Arreglo[1]**2+0.18*Arreglo[2]
**2+0.1*(Arreglo[0]*Arreglo[1])+0.04*(Arreglo[0]*Arreglo[2])+0.
06*(Arreglo[1]*Arreglo[2])-0.14*Arreglo[0]-0.11*Arreglo[1]-0.1*
Arreglo[2]+120+abs(Arreglo[0]+Arreglo[1]+Arreglo[2]-1000)-10
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This error occurs when I try to run the last function of my code and I have no idea why the function that I call at the end is already one that I had already used and it does not give me a problem, also if I try other methods such as defining another function appears the same mistake.
Thank´s for help

Comment: Apparently `Arreglo` is a single `int` value therefore `Arreglo[0]` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: chromosomes is a two-dimensional list what I do in the function is pass the rows to get the internal lists

Comment: split last line of code to many simpler steps (In separated lines) to get which element gives this error. You can also use `print()` to see what you really have in variables - it is called "print debuging". Maybe you have something different then `two-dimensional list`.

Comment: I will guess  `Cromosomas[ ...] = random.randint(1, 800)` it may assign single values instead rows - and it can make problem. But if you use `print()` then you will see if I am right.